# vue.js: Where to put regularly repeating background query

Tags: javascript, vue.js, background-process

I would like to query an API service every 15 seconds, so I can get data from a database and check whether something was changed. If there was a change, then my front end would update automatically because of how vue works.

```js
while (true) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        QueryService.orders().then(response => 
            this.orders = response.data
        )
    }, 15000)
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is this a good approach to solve such a problem at all?
2. What would be the best position in the code to place such a loop?

**EDIT:**

Using `setInterval()` seems to be the right way, but using a polling function with `setInterval` in the created() hook doesn't affect the data-table at all. It shows me "No data available":

```js
data () {
    return {
        headers [
            { ... },
            { ... }
        ],
        orders: []
}

created () {
    setInterval(function() { 
        QueryService.orders().then(response => this.orders = response.data)
    }, 15000)
}
```

Using the polling function without `setInterval` works and fills my data-table with data as usual:

```js
created () {
    QueryService.orders().then(response => this.orders = response.data)
}
```

Comment: suggest use subscriptions instead of polling

Comment: @DenisTsoi Do you have an example?

Answer (score 3):

For a simple and quick solution, I'd go with [I'mOnlyVueman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54767550/885535). Here some example code I found from [Vue.js polling using setINterval()](https://renatello.com/vue-js-polling-using-setinterval/). This example includes

- `pollData` method initiated on `created` that dispatches a store action (which would call the API)
- Canceling the poll as you navigate to another page using `beforeDestroy`

Code

```
data () {
    return {
        polling: null
    }
},
methods: {
    pollData () {
        this.polling = setInterval(() => {
            this.$store.dispatch('RETRIEVE_DATA_FROM_BACKEND')
        }, 3000)
    }
},
beforeDestroy () {
    clearInterval(this.polling)
},
created () {
    this.pollData()
}
```

But polling an API isn't very elegant and it doesn't scale well.  You'll likely need to do something with Websockets, setting up your app to listen for events pushed from your API.

Here's info on [Subscriptions in Vue-Apollo & GraphQL](https://www.howtographql.com/vue-apollo/8-subscriptions/) that Denis Tsoi mentioned.

> Subscriptions are a GraphQL feature that allows the server to send
>   data to the clients when a specific event happens on the backend.
>   Subscriptions are usually implemented with WebSockets, where the
>   server holds a steady connection to the client. That is, the
>   Request-Response-Cycle that we used for all previous interactions with
>   the API is not used for subscriptions. Instead, the client initially
>   opens up a steady connection to the server by specifying which event
>   it is interested in. Every time this particular event happens, the
>   server uses the connection to push the data that’s related to the
>   event to the client.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. `setInterval()` seems the right way, I can poll the data and `consol.log` it within the set interval, but the data is affecting my data-table. Unfortunately it is not being filled with data at all if I use setInterval. I have updated my question, so you can see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

A loop like this would go in the component's script within a `mounted ()` lifecycle hook.

That would mean once the component loads your loop would trigger. For detailed guidance on this technique the Vue docs are a good first stop, as well as this [article](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/).

Comment: I think you need to convert the while loop to a setInterval function. Because of the while loop the event loop is blocked forever, since your loop is always true. If you use setInterval on the function, it will run the data call every 15 seconds then free up the event loop again.

Comment: Unfortunately `setInterval` also freezes the browser. Any other suggestions how to solve this without a websocket?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with an example?  Seems like this should work. Here's an example. https://renatello.com/vue-js-polling-using-setinterval/

Comment: Are you still nesting in a while loop? If so, that's probably why it's still freezing. You don't need a while loop with setInterval - an if statement would suffice if you need a conditional (but it sounds like you don't). If you are not nesting in a while, this should work.

Comment: I was still using the loop. Without the loop I am getting the data in the defined interval, but unfortunately the data-table doesn't react to the data at all

Comment: I would recommend posting your code so we can see what's going on. Hard to tell from the description.

Comment: I see the issue now. If you look at W00ngy's code, you will see he instantiated a data field called "polling". This allows him to create a method function that sets the data variable via "this.polling" to the set interval function, which retrieves the data. So in order for your table to be reactive it probably needs this pattern, coming from a data property. Try mimicking W00ngy's example.

Comment: I have a data property and I also can update `this.orders`, but the problem is that vuetify data-table is not being updated with this data

Comment: Not sure what your template syntax looks like, but v-model or v-for would probably be required, depending on the structure of the data. If the data is one blob use v-model="orders". If it is an array or object use v-for="order in orders" and :key="order"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188703/discussion-between-saitam-and-imonlyvueman).